# Writing code for a time limited license

Tags: .net, licensing, httpwebrequest

A strategy I have seen implemented for this is to request a page from a website (google.com) and read the time header in the response to determine the true time rather than using the windows time (which can be changed by the user).

The only way that I know of circumventing this is that the user creates a local webserver and then points the website google.com (using the hosts file) to localhost.

I don't mind the user using my software illegally if he is willing to sacrifice the homepage of the internet since I believe he will not be able to open google.com as long as his host file redirects google.com to localhost to fake the timestamp.

My question is : Is there any way that the user will still be able to open google.com and run my software illegally?  (other than the obvious use of multiple machines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, they could configure their browser to use a proxy or, you know, just bookmark the IP address.

I don't know what the state of the art with these things is, but wouldn't it be enough to just keep track of the system time every time the app starts up, to see if it was rolled back?

Another common technique is to check the timestamps in a few common directories (system file, temp space, etc), if the clock was rolled back you'll likely see some timestamps from the future.

Of course if you want to be *really* paranoid, you can have it authenticate against your own server, in some cryptographically sound challenge-response scheme.  That one's more likely to cause problems and annoy people, though.

Comment: the good old bookmark the IP address .... a long time ago we used that in college :) forgot about it. The "keep track of the system time every time the app starts up, to see if it was rolled back" is cool :)  although the user might delete the file / registry key used to store it ..... maybe store it in the database for the software .... hmmmm plausable ... he deletes that file he loses the saved configuration. Thanks! And I don't need network access to start the application :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to work with proxies or connect to Google directly via their IP address. A reverse engineer (or cracker in this case) would not bother with those "hacks" (as in dodgy ways of circumventing the protection) but disassemble your application (as in proper way to circumvent the protection), find the location that is "protecting" your code - and patch that part. Say you create a method that returns true if it verifies the time was not changed, otherwise false. All the reverser would need to do is make that method to always return true, no matter weather he is even connected to the Internet (another reason why protection schemes that need Internet connections are a bad idea ... they require a Internet connection ^^). Or he could reverse engineer your key comparison algorithm - and create a key-generator.

Dongles have been cracked (a check of an online resource would be pretty similar), Steam was cracked a short time after its launch (Halflife needed online registration to run ... for a very little while ...). Even full online games have been "cracked" - for most MMO's you do find private servers which have been programmed from scratch. So even running all business logic of your application on your server won't protect it from ever being cracked.

I have reverse engineered copy protections myself in the past (among other things, I haven't been a cracker, but rather to learn how to protect my code) and often you could see how much time the programmer had spend writing those pieces of code, only to get beaten by changing a simple jmp-instruction.

IMHO a programmer should not waste *too much* time on the protection of his/her application. As long as the average user is not able to break it a protection is fine in most scenarios. More time spend on a protection means more wasted time, as there will always be someone able to break it.

So my advice: build a solid yet simple protection so that the average computer user cannot break it. And then move on.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just connect to Google (in your app) using the IP address? Then it can't be redirected by hosts file.

http://209.85.148.99/

Even better, do the DNS lookup yourself manually to bypass the hosts file.

Comment: this could just as easily be bypassed with: route -p add 209.85.148.99 mask 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1

Comment: +1 for the thought + DNS lookup idea.